# Invalid file format when saving with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

```
$file = '{full path and filename}';

//Read file
$file_type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( $file );
$excel_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($file_type);              
$this->php_excel = $excel_reader->load($file);              

//Set some values
$this->php_excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$this->php_excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$this->php_excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$this->php_excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
$this->php_excel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');

//Write to file new location    
$excel_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->php_excel, 'Excel2007' );
$excel_writer->save('c:\test.xls');
```

The `c:\test.xls` is created, but I get an error trying to load the Excel-file (from OpenOffice but I don't think that's the issue). The file I'm reading is about 260kb while the created test.xls is about 64kb. It says invalid and OpenOffice tries to repair the file when opening without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Excel2007` is the Writer for `.xlsx` files; `Excel5` is the Writer for `.xls` files... that difference is very important

Comment: Aha. Thank you very much! That made the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark Baker I figured out that I simply could change the line where I created the Writer to:

```
//Given that the file that are going to be saved should be of the same
//format that the read file has. 
$excel_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->php_excel, $file_type );
```